# How to write a binary blob onto disk on Informix

Tags: sql, informix

I have some images in an informix database, as a binary blob field (jpg), how can i write the images onto disk with an SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the data stored in a BYTE or a BLOB field?

If the data is stored in a BLOB column, then you can use:

```
SELECT LOTOFILE(blob_column, '/path/to/file/on/client', 'client')
  FROM TheTable
 WHERE PK_Column = 23411   -- PK value
```

If the data is stored in a BYTE column, then you have to work rather harder.  If you have ESQL/C (ClientSDK) and a C compiler on your machine, then I recommend obtaining SQLCMD from the [IIUG Software Archive](http://www.iiug.org/software/) and extracting the software.  You need your Informix environment set, and you need to be able to compile C programs.  Then run:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/bin
```

It doesn't much matter what you specify as the prefix - you just need to run the configure script.

You can then either compile everything (`make`), or you can simply compile the program `selblob` (`make selblob`).  That program is what I call a 'vignette'; a microscopic program that shows how to select a BYTE blob to disk.  It is, however, also fully-functional; it will work with just about anything that you throw at it, or diagnose an error.

If your database is called `precious`, the byte data is in a table `byte_table`, the column holding the data is `byte_column`, and the primary key columns are `col1` (and the value required is `23`) and `col2` (and the value required is `"Habeas Corpus"`), then you can run:

```
selblob -d precious -t byte_table -k col1=23 -k col2="Habeas Corpus" \
        -c byte_column -f output_file
```

This will unload the byte value into the named file.

If you don't have ESQL/C or a C compiler or permission to use them, then life is more difficult.  The closest approach is to use the UNLOAD statement in DB-Access:

```
dbaccess precious - <<!
unload to "output_file"
select byte_column from byte_table where col1 = 23 and col2 = 'Habeas Corpus';
!
```

This will create a file containing a hex-dump of the byte value (2 bytes per character).  You then need to post-process the file to convert the hex into regular data.  Note that if the column was a TEXT column instead of a BYTE column, then no conversion would be needed.  You can use a fairly simple Perl script to do the conversion (provided the file is small enough to be slurped into memory - you have to work harder if it is not small enough):

```
perl -w -e '
    $/ = "";
    my $data = <>;
    while (length($data) > 1)
    {
        my $hex = substr($data, 0, 2);
        printf "%c", hex($hex);
        $data = substr($data, 2);
    }' <output_file
```

The length condition specifies '`> 1`' to deal with the newline at the end of the unloaded data.

(For 'hysterical raisins', aka 'historical reasons', I still call both BYTE and TEXT 'blob types', even though IDS 9.00 introduced the explicit names BLOB and CLOB for 'smart blobs', a slightly different pair of data types with roughly corresponding functionality - in my book, they're all blob (lower-case) types.  That's the trouble with old guys who learned about BYTE and TEXT blobs in 1990, six years or more before BLOB and CLOB blobs were added.
In any case, there isn't a good alternative official terminology for the older style blobs; using 'dumb blobs' is not politically correct!)

Comment: you're insane jon... I needed this answer as well and of course its going to be your answer if its got anything to do with informix

Comment: Apparently LOTOFILE works on BYTE columns too, at least in Informix 12.10.
Thanks for all the useful Informix posts, every time I search something on Informix your name pops up :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a small program that queries the database and saves the blobs to disk. Most databases have no notion of "open file on disk".