# how to insert blob or clob column in informix

Tags: blob, informix, clob

I am new to informix database. I want to know how to insert blob and clob type of column in informix. I need sample query for those two type of column. If someone help, I will appreciate...

Comment: Which programming language and which binding/library do you use?

Comment: See [How to write a binary blob onto disk in Informix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445191/how-to-write-a-binary-blob-onto-disk-on-informix) for the selection part of the answer: see [Operations on blob data in Informix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467562/operations-on-blob-data-in-informix/) for some information about other functions to help.  You do need to specify the programming language and binding you plan to use; the answers for ESQL/C are different from ODBC, JDBC, ...

Answer (score 0):

This is my Jython code that uses JDBC and prepared statements to test both `INSERT` and `SELECT` of `blob` from Informix database:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jython
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import time

from java.sql import DriverManager
from java.lang import Class
from java.io import FileInputStream
from java.io import ByteArrayOutputStream

Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver")

"""
create table _blob_test_so (
    id serial,
    txt varchar(30),
    column_blob blob
);
"""


def test_blob_insert(db):
    print('inserting gif picture into blob table...')
    blob = FileInputStream('snoopy_comics20121023.gif')
    insert_stmt = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO _blob_test_so (txt, column_blob) VALUES (?, ?)")
    insert_stmt.setString(1, 'test %s' % (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
    insert_stmt.setBinaryStream(2, blob)
    rec_cnt = insert_stmt.executeUpdate()
    blob.close()
    insert_stmt.close()
    print('records changed: %d' % (rec_cnt))


def test_blob_select(db):
    print('selecting data from blob table...')
    pstm = db.prepareStatement("SELECT id, txt, column_blob FROM _blob_test_so")
    rs = pstm.executeQuery()
    while (rs.next()):
        id = rs.getInt(1)
        txt = rs.getString(2)
        image_stream = rs.getBinaryStream(3)
        fout = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        while 1:
            b = image_stream.read()
            if b < 0:
                break
            fout.write(b)
        arr = fout.toByteArray()
        fname_out = 'test_%s.gif' % (id)
        print('%d:%s: fname: %s %d [b]' % (id, txt, fname_out, len(arr)))
        f = open(fname_out, 'wb')
        f.write(arr)
        f.close()
    rs.close()


db = DriverManager.getConnection('jdbc:informix-sqli://test-informix:9088/test:informixserver=ol_testifx;DB_LOCALE=pl_PL.CP1250;CLIENT_LOCALE=pl_PL.CP1250;charSet=CP1250', 'user', 'passwd')
test_blob_insert(db)
test_blob_select(db)
```